# Not able to read individual page using PDFTextStripper with multiple threads

Tags: java, apache, pdfbox

I am able to create 10 threads. But the problem is when I try to access individual page using those threads in parallel style. I have tried putting the private static PDFTextStripper instance into synchronized block as well. Still I get below exception:

COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?

trying to print first word from each page for first 10 pages, but its not working. This is my first experiment with Multithreading and PDF reading. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class ReadPDFFile extends Thread implements FileInstance {
    private static String fileLocation;
    private static String fileNameIV;
    private static String userInput;
    private static int userConfidence;
    private static int totalPages;
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<String>> map = null;
    private Iterator<PDDocument> iteratorForThisDoc;
    private PDFTextStripperByArea text;
    private static PDFTextStripper pdfStrip = null;
    private static PDFParser pdParser = null;
    private Splitter splitter;
    private static int counter=0;
    private StringWriter writer;
    private static  ReentrantLock counterLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    private static PDDocument doc;
    private static PDDocument doc2;
    private static boolean flag = false;
    List<PDDocument> listOfPages;

    ReadPDFFile(String filePath, String fileName, String userSearch, int confidence) throws FileNotFoundException{
        fileLocation= filePath;
        fileNameIV =  fileName;
        userInput= userSearch;
        userConfidence = confidence;
        System.out.println("object created");
    }

    @Override
    public void createFileInstance(String filePath, String fileName) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
        try(PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath))){
            doc = document;
            pdfStrip = new PDFTextStripper();
            this.splitter = new Splitter();
            text = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
            document.getClass();
            if(!document.isEncrypted()) {
                totalPages = document.getNumberOfPages();
                System.out.println("Number of pages in this book "+totalPages);
                listOfPages = splitter.split(document);
                iteratorForThisDoc = listOfPages.iterator();
            }
            this.createThreads();
            /*
             * for(int i=0;i<1759;i++) { readThisPage(i, pdfStrip); } flag= true;
             */
        }
        catch(IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createThreads() {
        counter=1;
        for(int i=0;i<=9;i++) {
            ReadPDFFile pdf = new ReadPDFFile();
            pdf.setName("Reader"+i);
            pdf.start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(counter < 10){
                int pgNum= pageCounterReentrant();
                readThisPage(pgNum, pdfStrip);
            }
            doc.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
        }   
        flag= true;
    }

    public static int getCounter() {
        counter=  counter+1;
        return counter;
    }

    public static int pageCounterReentrant() {
        counterLock.lock();
        try {
            counter =  getCounter();
        } finally {
            counterLock.unlock();
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public static void readThisPage(int pageNum, PDFTextStripper ts) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" reading page: "+pageNum+", counter: "+counter);

        synchronized(ts){
            String currentpageContent= new String();
            try {
                ts.setStartPage(pageNum);
                ts.setEndPage(pageNum);
                System.out.println("-->"+ts.getPageEnd());
                currentpageContent = ts.getText(doc);
                currentpageContent = currentpageContent.substring(0, 10);
                System.out.println("\n\n "+currentpageContent);
            }

        /*
         * further operations on currentpageContent here
         */

            catch(IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
            }
        } 
    }

    public static void printFinalResult(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<String>> map) {
        /*
         * simply display content of ConcurrentHashMap
         */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Search Word");
        userInput = sc.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Confidence"); 
        userConfidence = sc.nextInt(); 
        ReadPDFFile pef = new ReadPDFFile("file path", "file name",userInput, userConfidence);
        pef.createFileInstance("file path ","file name");
        if(flag==true)
            printFinalResult(map);
     }
}
```

If I read each page in a for loop sequentially using one thread then it is able to print the content, but not with multithreads. You can see that code commented in void createFileInstance(), after this.createThreads();  I wish to get string content of each pdf page individually, using threads, and then perform operation on it. I have the logic to collect each word token into List but before moving ahead, I need to solve this problem.

Comment: this is apache PDFBox library by the way

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like this:

```
try(PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath))){
    doc = document;
    ....
    this.createThreads();
} // document gets closed here
...
//threads that do text extraction still running here (and using a closed object)
```

These threads use doc to extract the text (`ts.getText(doc)`). However at this time, the PDDocument object is already closed due to the usage of [try-with-resources](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources), and its streams also closed. Thus the error message "Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?".

You should create the thread before closing the document, and waiting for all threads to finish before closing it.

I'd advise against using multithreading on one PDDocument, see [PDFBOX-4559](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4559). You could create several PDDocuments and then extract on these, or not do it at all. Text extraction works pretty fast in PDFBox (compared to rendering).

Comment: yeah but I have declared my doc variable as private static in the beginning of the class definition. So I think that variable should now be available class wide, right !! By that I mean, there should not be any problem if i use it outside the try block or outside the method

Comment: In Java this is just a reference to the object, that has been closed. The actual PDDocument object is closed when `document` goes out of scope, due to you using try-with-resources.

Comment: I just corrected the formatting of the code. `createThreads` actually is called *inside* the try-with-resources. Nonetheless, your underlying reasoning most likely is correct, only the document is closed not before the threads started but while they run.

Comment: @mkl thank you. I have changed the answer accordingly.